# Java - copy directory & skip non existing files

Tags: java, spring, file, apache-commons

I'm using `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils` to copy a directory - with all its sub-directories & files - to a different location:

```
try {
   FileUtils.copyDirectory(new File(srcDir), new File(destDir));
} catch (IOException ex) {
   log.error("Exception while copying report directory from: " + srcDir + ", to: " + destDir, ex);
}
```

However, for some reason I get a `java.io.FileNotFoundException` for 1 file.
I don't want to fail altogether, but instead to copy the other files.
Is it possible with `FileUtils`? Or do I need to handle that manually?